# KQL Query to filter values based on condition

Tags: azure, kql, azure-sentinel

Need help on filtering the user domain from userprincipalname collected from sentinel signin logs. I have all user domains separated out from upn as below.

extend UserDomains = split(UserPrincipalName,'@')[1]

In addition to the UserDomains, I need internal domains and external domains.
How can I filter UserDomains based on a particular conditions further.

Cheers !

Comment: And what exactly is the difference between internal and external domains?

Comment: Internal domains are domains consumed by my organization. 

Eg, mycompany.com, us.mycompany.com, uk.mycompany.com etc.

External Domains are of domains of users who are outside of my company, but logging in an application as gust user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use operators like [iif](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ifffunction):

```
T 
| extend IsInternalDomain = iif(UserDomains contains "mycompany.com", true, false)
| where IsInternalDomain
```

or

```
T 
| extend DomainType = iif(UserDomains contains "mycompany.com", "Internal", "External")
| where DomainType == "Internal"
```

Or the [case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/casefunction) operator:

```
T 
| extend DomainType = case(UserDomains contains "us.mycompany.com", "Internal US", 
                           UserDomains contains "mycompany.com", "Internal",
                           "External")
| where DomainType == "Internal US"
```

Or you can simply use a `where` like this:

```
T 
| where UserDomains !endswith "mycompany.com" // include only external domains
```